# How to prevent screen randomly dimming on Win10 desktop PC

Tags: windows-10, display

I am running Win10 Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044 on a home built box, and am very frustrated by the screen seemingly randomly dimming the screen.  It usually happens for text, black type on white background, such as when I have a PDF open or a text document, though it also occasionally happens for web pages (in any browser) as well.

The graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, if that makes any difference.  Has the latest drivers, and there isn't anything obvious in the control panels related to screen dimming.

I'm guessing it's something trying to be 'helpful' to reduce eye strain or something when viewing something that is mostly white.

I've tried changing the power plan (no option for adapative brightness) and there isn't anything I can find in the display settings.  Night light is off.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to "adaptive" or "auto" brightness (and contrast) settings. There may be *two* control panels (CPL) to change these settings:

- The [Native Windows CPL](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-auto-or-adaptive-screen-brightness-in-windows-10/)

and

- [The NVIDIA CPL.](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/207548/turn-off-auto-brightness-contrast-etc/)
- Also, third-party software such as [MSI X Boost](https://msi-x-boost.software.informer.com/) have been cited as the cause of that issue.

Aside from simply *changing* settings, other suggestions to fix the issue include [changing](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/7b0kpb/fix_for_windows_10_resetting_nvidia_color_profile/) or [removing the NVIDIA color profile](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/7k8vxh/how_to_fix_nvida_control_panel_colors_resetting/), uninstalling MSI X Boost, reverting to older versions of Adobe PDF Viewer or Illustrator, and using third-party PDF viewers such as [Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) or [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/).

Hopefully, one of these will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I've read all those too, and none of them addresses the issue. As I wrote, there is no adaptive brightness option in this box's WinCPL, nor in the Nvidia one, and no MSI software is installed (not using an MSI branded component). The color profile stuff doesn't actually apply to the situation I'm describing, alas.  And I have been using FoxIt for my PDF reader.  So unfortunately I'm still stuck...